# gv under Debian testing, Bookworm

Tags: debian

When I try to view any pdf file with gv, all I get is a whirling cursor on a blank page.

I used dpkg to install from stable, oldstable, experimental, unstable - same result.

Answer (score 0):

[`gv` is broken in Debian testing](https://bugs.debian.org/1024327), possibly because of [a Ghostscript bug](https://bugs.debian.org/1023330). Downgrading the latter might fix things for you. Failing that, you’ll have to wait for a fix, or use another tool to view PDF files.

Comment: Blah, no problem Stephen.   Thanks a lot for the response.   Thanks a lot for Debian and thanks a lot for Testing.   It cured another more serious problem I hand.